How to create an "Artist (Songtitle)" Formatted Index in Songs package
CONTEXT: This brilliant answer already described how one can create a title index that looks like this:
Lady in Black (Uriah Heep) ........ 4
Lemon Tree (Fool's Garden) ........ 6

QUESTION: How can I create an author index that looks like this:

Minimum solution: Simple Artist (Title) format:

Uriah Heep (Lady in Black) ........ 4
Uriah Heep (Rainbox Demon) ........ 5
Fool's Garden (Lemon Tree) ........ 6


Ideal solution: Hierarchy List Artist >Title format:

Uriah Heep
   Lady in Black ........ 4
   Rainbox Demon ........ 5
Fool's Garden
   Lemon Tree ........... 6

This is surprisingly difficult and has cost me many hours already. I can't overcome the following issues:

Handling of spaces in song titles (producing Black), Uriah Heep (Lady in see below)
Handling of multiple authors (producing Tree), Fool's Garden see below)

STATUS QUO:
I am currently using this code
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[chorded]{songs}
\usepackage{xpatch}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% INDEX CREATION %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\getfirstartist}[1]{%
    \expandafter\@getfirstartist#1,\@nil%
}
\def\@getfirstartist#1,#2\@nil{#1}

\newcommand{\getfirsttitle}[1]{%
    \expandafter\@getfirsttitle#1,\@nil%
}
\def\@getfirsttitle#1,#2\@nil{#1}

\newcommand{\addparentheses}[2]{%
    \ifx\relax#2\relax#1\else#1 (#2)\fi
}

\patchcmd{\SB@@@beginsong}
{\SB@addtoindexes\songtitle\SB@rawrefs\songauthors}
{\SB@addtoindexes
    {\addparentheses{\songtitle}{\getfirstartist{\songauthors}}}
    \SB@rawrefs
    {\addparentheses{\songauthors}{\getfirsttitle{\songtitle}}}}
{}{}
\makeatother

\newauthorindex{autor}{autor} 
\newindex{titel}{titel}
\indexsongsas{autor}{\thepage}
\indexsongsas{titel}{\thepage}

\begin{document}
    \showindex{Author index}{autor}
    \showindex{Title index}{titel}
    \begin{songs}{autor,titel}
        
        \beginsong{Lady In Black}[by={Uriah\ Heep}]
        \beginverse*
        ...
        \endverse
        \endsong
        
        \beginsong{Rainbow Demon}[by={Uriah\ Heep}]
        \beginverse*
        ...
        \endverse
        \endsong
        
        \beginsong{Lemon Tree}[by={Fool's\ Garden, Peter\ Freudenthaler, Volker\ Hinkel}]
        \beginverse*
        ...
        \endverse
        \endsong
        
        \beginsong{Orange Tree}[by={Someone\ else}]
        \beginverse 
        ...
        \endverse
        \endsong
    \end{songs}
\end{document}

Producing this output:
Looks great:

Needs work:

REFERENCES & COMMENTS:
This person (github) is generating a beatiful index, but using some external JS code as far as I understand.
Some extracts from songs.sty that might be helpful in explaining how index entries are handled:
    \begingroup%
      \def\'{}\def\{}\def\v{}\def\u{}\def\={}\def\^{}%
      \def\.{}\def\H{}\def\~{}\def\"{}\def\t{}%
      \def\copyright{(c)}%
      \let~\space%
      \let\par\SB@printEOL%
      \let\#\SB@hash%
      \let\&\SB@amp%
      \catcode|9 %
      \catcode*9 %
      \catcode^9 %
      \def\[##1]{}%
      \resettitles%
      \immediate\write\SB@txtout{\thesongnum. \songtitle}%
      \nexttitle%
      \foreachtitle{\immediate\write\SB@txtout{(\songtitle)]]%
      \ifx\songauthors\@empty\else%
         \immediate\write\SB@txtout{\songauthors}%
      \fi%
      \ifx\SB@rawrefs\@empty\else%
         \immediate\write\SB@txtout{\SB@rawrefs}%
      \fi%
      \immediate\write\SB@txtout{}%
      \SB@doEOLfalse%
      \obeylines%
  }

\newcommand\SB@@@beginsong{%
  \global\SB@stanzafalse%
  \setbox\SB@chorusbox\box\voidb@x%
  \SB@gotchorusfalse%
  \setbox\SB@songbox\vbox\bgroup\begingroup%
    \ifnum\SB@numcols>\z@\hsize\SB@colwidth\fi%
    \leftskip\z@skip\rightskip\z@skip%
    \parfillskip\@flushglue\parskip\z@skip%
    \SB@raggedright%
    \global\SB@transposefactor\z@%
    \global\SB@cr@{\\}%
    \protected@edef\@currentlabel{\p@songnum\thesongnum}%
    \setcounter{versenum}{1}%
    \SB@prevversetrue%
    \meter44%
    \resettitles%
    \SB@addtoindexes\songtitle\SB@rawrefs\songauthors%
    \nexttitle%
    \foreachtitle{\expandafter\SB@addtotitles\expandafter{\songtitle]]%
    \resettitles%
    \lyricfont\relax%
    \SB@setbaselineskip%
}

    \SB@addtoindexes\songtitle\SB@rawrefs\songauthors%

\newcommand\newauthorindex{\SB@newindex3{AUTHOR INDEX DATA FILE]]
\@onlypreamble\newauthorindex


Here is a way to obtain your ideal solution using package makeidx. Just follw the procedure given in the code.
The key is to build index hierarchie via the !.
1. Straight forward

\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\title{A demo for music indices}
% ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\begin{document}
\maketitle

Procedure:
\begin{itemize}
  \item write your document
  \item set hierarchical indices as shown in code
  \item compile (will store index entries)
  \item ! open a terminal, run in this directory:
  \item makeindex YOURFILENAME
  \item compile again (will assign page numbers)
\end{itemize}

\section{Uriah Heep} 

\index{Uriah Heep!Rainbow Demon}
Rainbow Demon \dots

\newpage    % just to change pages
\index{Uriah Heep!Lady in Black}
Lady in Black \dots

\section{Fools Garden}
\index{Fools Garden!Lemon Tree}
 Lemon Tree \dots
 
\newpage
\section{The Police}
\index{The Police!Messate in a Bottle}
Message in a Bottle \dots

\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Index}
\printindex
\end{document}

2. Some refinement
The previous code assumes you run from your command line, where the > just denotes the prompt:
> makeindex YOURFILE

Now makindex allows customization via .ist files, like so, here to fill the various levels with dots:
YOURFILE.ist:
delim_0 "\\dotfill"
delim_1 "\\dotfill"

(Level 0 would be needed, if you'd put \index{Uriah Heep} somewhere, e.g. with the \section.)
After running this on the command line (after the first compile)
> makeindex -s YOURFILE.ist YOURFILE

you'll obtain after the 2nd compile, i.e. unchanged main document:

3. Mulit-indices
Topic index on ctan provides many more alternatives. Most likely using package imakeidx will provide the last two examples of your question.
However, BECAUSE it sounds like a second question (which we don't want here: 1 question == 1 problem), and it seems to be a bit under construction, I can't provide code using this package: it's pretty straightforward, if you managed to run the two examples above.
